# Photoshop conditional renaming script

Tags: photoshop, photoshop-script

I am trying to write a script for Photoshop to find if a certain layer exists in the document and then if it does, to rename it. I could do it in Python but am quite confused by the scripting used by Photoshop. So, in Python it would look something like this:

```
def myfunction (psd):
   for (layer in psd):
       if ( layer == “layer_name”):
           layer = “new_layer_name”
```

How can this be done in Photoshop?

Comment: This looks like what you want... https://community.adobe.com/t5/illustrator/a-script-to-find-and-replace-layer-names/td-p/4960031?page=1

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell that's nearly exactly what I need. The only issue is it gives me this error: "Error 1302: No such element" for line 19: if (layernames[currentLayer.name]) {

Comment: Maybe try clicking `edit` under your question and updating it to your latest/greatest attempt. Then folks will see what you are doing exactly (without dredging through the comments) and the line numbers in the error message will match up.

Comment: Thanks @MarkSetchell I figured it's a distinct question so I've opened another question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63358636/photoshop-2020-error-1302-no-such-element

Answer (score 0):

It's quite simple provided you don't have layer groups - and then it get's a bit more complicated.

So, you've got your psd with five or so layers in, one of them is called "spoon" by accident. This will rename it from "spoon" "my layer name".

```
// call the source document
var srcDoc = app.activeDocument;

renameLayer(srcDoc);

function renameLayer(psd)
{
  var numOfLayers = psd.layers.length;

  // main loop
  for (var i = numOfLayers -2; i >= 0; i--) // ignore background
  {
    var thisLayer = psd.layers[i];

    if (thisLayer.name == "spoon")
    {
      // do stuff!
      psd.activeLayer = psd.artLayers[i];
      var rename = "my layer name";
      psd.activeLayer.name = rename;
    }
  }
}
```

However, if you have groups then you'll need to loop over all the layers with something like this.

```
// group layer vegetables
var allLayers = new Array();
var theLayers = collectAllLayers(app.activeDocument, 0);


// function collect all layers
function collectAllLayers (theParent, level)
{
   for (var m = theParent.layers.length - 1; m >= 0; m--)
   {
      var theLayer = theParent.layers[m];
      
      // apply the function to layersets;
      if (theLayer.typename == "ArtLayer")

      {
         // find the art layers
         doStuff(theLayer)
      }
      else
      {
         allLayers.push(level + theLayer.name);
         collectAllLayers(theLayer, level + 1)
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Most of Photoshop's document object collections include the built-in method `getByName(String name)` for querying the collection by name ([see full list here](https://theiviaxx.github.io/photoshop-docs/search.html?q=getbyname&check_keywords=yes&area=default)). The method performs a case-sensitive search, returning the first object with a matching `name` property, or throwing if none found.

While in this case a simple recursive function traversing across artLayers and into layerSets is most effective, one could also (ab)use the `getByName` method to perform recursive renaming...

```js
function renameByName(col, find, replace) {
    for (var i = 0; i < col.layerSets.length; i++)
        renameByName(col.layerSets[i], find, replace);

    try {
        while (col.artLayers.getByName(find).name = replace);
    } catch (e) { }
}

// Use like...
renameByName(app.activeDocument, "Stelio", "Stelio Was Here");
```